# search query where I filter on a propertybag property value, missing some results

Tags: search-results

I am using sp 2013 onpremises. I have created a propertybag "teamleads". I did a full crawl. I see now a crawled property. I created a managed property and connect it to this crawled property. I did a full crawl.

Now I fill the propertybag of 36 site collections with the value "khaj". I did a full crawl on the webapplication of this 12 site collections.

No I go to the search page and enter this query in the search box:

```
teamleads:khaj ContentClass:STS_site
```

I see only 12 of the 36 site collections. Why do I missing the other results?

UPDATE!
In the sp 2013 search tool I can see all results when I turn off the option "trim duplicates"!

Also in the search result webpart I have check out the "duplicate" option.

what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exported the webpart and edited the xml. I changed this property:

"TrimDuplicates":false

I uploaded the webpart and now it works great! But why do I need to edit this in xml?? Isnt there another solution in the GUI of sharepoint?